# Complex SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have a complex SSH tunnel problem I'm trying to solve and can't seem to get it quite right.

Simply put:

ME -> Bastion:22 -> Instance:8500

Bastion uses a different username and key than instance. I would like to be able to access port 1234 on instance from localhost:1234

Right now I have the following:

```
Host bastion
  HostName bastion.example.com
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  User spanky

Host internal
  ForwardAgent yes
  HostName consul.internal
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/aws.pem
  ProxyJump bastion
  User ec2-user
  Port 8500
```

But I don't think I've got it.

The following two commands work, but I'm trying to distill them into a working config:

```
ssh -L 2222:10.0.0.42:22 bastion.example.com -N -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
ssh -L 8500:localhost:8500 ec2-user@localhost -N -i ~/.ssh/aws.pem -p 2222
```

Answer (score 0):

With a current version of ssh, you should be able to use:

`ssh -L1234:localhost:1234 -J spanky@bastion.example.com ec2-user@consul.internal`

From `man ssh`:

> ```
>  -J destination
>          Connect to the target host by first making a ssh 
>          connection to the jump host described by destination and then
>          establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there. 
>           Multiple jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters.
>           This is a shortcut to specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.
> ```